# How can I create HttpResponseDatagram and HttpResponseLayer in pcap.net

Tags: c#, http, tcp, pcap.net

I cant create these objects in pcap.net

```
IpV4Datagram ip = packet.Ethernet.IpV4;
        TcpDatagram tcp = ip.Tcp;
        HttpDatagram http = tcp.Http;
     //   HttpResponseDatagram resdat=http.;  How can i create them?
     //   HttpResponseLayer resp;
if (tcp.Http.Body != null && http.IsResponse)
            body = resp.Body.ToString();
```

I'm trying to get HTTP Response Body from a tcp packet. If there is another way to do it can someone help?

Comment: Is there a reason that you are working at the _packet_ lever? Most sites run a packet size in the area of 1460 bytes, and a typical page has content many times that.

Comment: I 'm making a tcp listener i listen all the packets coming. It's not a problem with packet count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [Pcap.Net User Guide](https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net/wiki/User-Guide), there's [a section about sending packets](https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net/wiki/Pcap.Net-Tutorial-Sending-Packets).
In that section, there is an example on how to create `HttpRequestLayer`, and creating `HttpResponseLayer` is very similar.

> ```
>  HttpRequestLayer httpLayer =
>      new HttpRequestLayer
>      {
>          Version = HttpVersion.Version11,
>          Header = new HttpHeader(new HttpContentLengthField(11)),
>          Body = new Datagram(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hello world")),
>          Method = new HttpRequestMethod(HttpRequestKnownMethod.Get),
>          Uri = @"http://pcapdot.net/",
>      };
> ```

HttpResponseDatagram is creating by parsing an HTTP packet.
For example, by doing

```
packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Tcp.Http
```

There's no simple way of creating a `Datagram` without parsing a packet.